# select statement, using a variable and incrementing said variable

Tags: mysql

I am using an older version of MySql, trying to simulate row_number(). To do this I am following a tutorial, and the line commented out is not working.

So I have tried to deconstruct the increment element without the IF.

At present @merchant_rank is producing 5 rows of NULL. Any ideas why?

```
SELECT merchant, 
       name, 
       @current_merchant := merchant AS 'current merchant',
       /*@merchant_rank := IF(@current_merchant = 'merchant, @merchant_rank + 1, null) AS 'merchant_rank'*/
       @merchant_rank := @merchant_rank + 1 AS 'merchant_rank'
FROM products_en
ORDER BY merchant
LIMIT 5
```

for posterity

Including `SET @merchant_rank := 0;` before the SELECT statement worked:

```
SET @merchant_rank := 0;
SELECT merchant, 
       name, 
       @current_merchant := merchant AS 'current merchant',
       @merchant_rank := @merchant_rank + 1 AS 'merchant_rank'
FROM products_en
ORDER BY merchant
LIMIT 5
```

This also works

```
SELECT merchant, 
       name, 
       @current_merchant := merchant AS 'current merchant',
       @merchant_rank := IF(merchant=@current_merchant, @merchant_rank + 1, 1) AS 'merchant_rank'
FROM (SELECT @merchant_rank:=0) AS _init, products_en
ORDER BY merchant
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: *I am following a tutorial* Eithier exactly you forget to initialize variables or this is bad tutorial...

Comment: @Akina thank you for your response, yes, both scenarios are entirely plausible concurrently and independent of one another.

Comment: @Akina not sure if you were playing mind tricks with me however augmenting the tutorial code with ```SET @merchant_rank := 0;``` made the row counter work. Thank you!

Comment: Another trick I've seen is `... FROM (SELECT @merchant_rank:=0) AS _init, products_en ...` so the initialization is built into the query. The downside is you have to explain how it works to every person who reads the query.

Comment: @BillKarwin your suggestion works great, it is pure alchemy to me. +1